# "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item" when using ThemeDictionaryExtension in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I'm using multiple assemblies for my WPF project. One of these is defining some custom controls that extend standard ones like DataGrid. These custom controls are all defined in an assembly referenced by my main executable assembly.

Because I'm using multiple `Generic.xaml` files in my custom control assembly to define a default style for the controls, I want my main executable assembly to also apply these default styles. Therefore, I added the following lines to my `App.xaml` file of my main executable assembly:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="{ThemeDictionary CustomControlsAssembly}" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary >
</Application.Resources>
```

At runtime, this works as expected. However, my Visual Studio is always reporting the following error at the exact line where my `ThemeDictionary` Extension is declared:

`Error  1   Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: item`

Have I missed out on something or is this just a false positive error of my Visual Studio 2013 (also appears on 2015)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify the default control themes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743330/how-to-modify-the-default-control-themes)

Comment: No, my question is about an error when setting a Default Control Theme, the question you linked is about how to implement it in general.